# Java: Is there a difference between L and l (lowercase L) when specifying a long?

Tags: java, types, wrapper, long-integer

When I specify a number to be a `long` with a constant value `400`, is there any difference between using `400L` and `400l`?

Does it have some relationship to the wrapper type? Is `L` used to get a wrapper `Long` and `l` for the primitive data type `long`?

Answer (score 43):

No *practical* difference. Either `L` or `l` can be used, both indicate a `long` primitive. Also, either can be [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to the corresponding `Long` wrapper type.

However, it is worth noting that [JLS-3.10.1 - Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says (in part)

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).
>
> *The suffix `L` is preferred, because the letter `l` (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (one).*

Comment: Don't longs give null pointer exceptions more frequently than Longs though?

Comment: So, long story short primarily that difference l vs L is kept just for keeping it more readable. (And to prevent confusion from digit 1)

Answer (score 24):

Yes: it's readability.

It's easy to mistake `400l` for four thousand and one when you first glance at it.

I find it more likely to interpret it correctly as four hundred long with the upper case L.

Comment: Then why do they have lowercase long as an object type?

Comment: @CollinFox `long` is a primitive 64-bit data type in Java. `Long` is an object type.